# If I enable compression in IIS, do I need to change my webservice?

Tags: c#, iis, compression

I'm quite unfamiliar with the compression parameters to be set in IIS. My question is if I need to change my backend (.NET framework webservice) in case I want to have GZIP compression allowed?

Background info, we have a webservice running on IIS with compression enabled.
[image: See picture of IIS]

When doing a request I enabled Content-Encoding.

[image: picture of encoding]

But in my response I see no such header containing content-encoding:

[image: content encoding in response]

What am I missing? Or do I need to change my backend service as well to have the gzip encoding enabled?

Comment: Is your problem solved? Any progress on this issue? Looking forward to your reply, thank you！

Answer (score 0):

If your request headers contain the correct Accept-Encoding, but the response headers do not have a Content-Encoding header, I recommend that you enable failed request tracing in IIS and check the trace logs to see if the compression module is successful.

This link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed content:
https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis.

This issue is most likely because the antivirus software on your computer is stripping out the Content-Encoding response header. Actually gzipping is applied, but the antivirus protects the http connection, unzip the response to check it, and then dynamically rewrites the response headers.

You can try temporarily turning off Windows Defender or antivirus software on your computer and then test to see if you get content encoding in the response headers.

Similar threads：

[IIS application missing Content-Encoding - gzip in Response Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250376/iis-application-missing-content-encoding-gzip-in-response-header)

[IIS Compression missing content-encoding in response even though logs show it working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106677/iis-compression-missing-content-encoding-in-response-even-though-logs-show-it-wo)

[The Story About Compression & Antivirus](https://medium.com/@mishani0x0ef/iis-compression-the-mental-model-a0b4fad78c74)